# How to add a view to tableViewController [Swift]

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

In my swift app I've a tableViewController, and I want to add a view.
Here's my code:

```
func animateViewIn() {

    alertView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    alertView.center = self.view.center

    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(alertView)
}
```

But it doesn't work, I also tried to use view.addSubview().
What object have I to use?
Thank you

Comment: I'm pretty sure you missed the frame-property. Try to add `alertView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you show last code you tried ?

Comment: may be color match try **alertView.backgroundColor = .red**

Comment: Are you trying to dd this view as a (1) cell, (2) part of a cell, (3) header, (4) section, (5) something else? Honestly, it matter. Also, are you using auto layout? If so, where? These detail are important! Finally, if you could *without* a total code dump, could you provide *enough* code for me to duplicate your issue? Four lines of code and saying "it doesn't work" isn't nearly enough. Thanks!

Comment: Table view and Table view Controllers are special. Create ContainerViewController and then add the table view controller as a child view controller to the BaseViewController. Then add your custom view to that BaseViewController. So BaseViewController would have 2 subviews (table view and custom view)